# Search bar in list-view JSON parsed data error NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, search, android-studio

My app is parsing data fron a JSON url and displaying it in a listview.

I want to make a search bar to search between the items in the lisview but I have a NullPointerException error when I try to search something.

I think it has to do something with the **adapter**.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "JSONURL";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_ABV = "abv";
    private static final String TAG_IBU = "ibu";
    //private static final String TAG_ISORGANIC = "isOrganic";
    //private static final String TAG_YEAR = "year";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray data = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();


        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();

                String abv = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.abv))
                        .getText().toString();

                String ibu = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ibu))
                        .getText().toString();

                //String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description))
                //.getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ABV, abv);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ABV, ibu);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    data = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                    // looping through All beers
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {


                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        String ibu;

                        if(c.has("ibu")) {
                            ibu = c.getString(TAG_IBU);
                        } else {
                            ibu = "No ibu value";
                        }

                       String abv;

                        if(c.has("abv")) {
                            abv = c.getString(TAG_ABV);
                        } else {
                            abv = "No abv value";
                        }

                        String description;

                        if(c.has("description")) {
                            description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                        } else {
                            description = "No description available";
                        }

                        //String abv = c.getString(TAG_ABV);

                        //String ibu = c.getString(TAG_IBU);

                        //String isOrganic = c.getString(TAG_ISORGANIC);

                        //String year = c.getString(TAG_YEAR);



                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        data.put(TAG_ID, id);

                        data.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        //data.put(TAG_YEAR, year);

                        data.put(TAG_IBU, ibu);

                        data.put(TAG_ABV, abv);

                        data.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                        // adding beer to beer list
                        dataList.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, dataList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_IBU, TAG_ABV},
                    new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.ibu, R.id.abv });

            inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

This is the error:

```
08-31 20:01:40.372  13714-13714/com.javapapers.android.jsonparsing W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41762db8)
08-31 20:01:40.382  13714-13714/com.javapapers.android.jsonparsing E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.javapapers.android.jsonparsing, PID: 13714
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.peeters.ward.beerdroid.MainActivity$GetContacts$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:249)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
            at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7467)
            at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9187)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
            at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:675)
            at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:197)
            at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 20:01:41.762  13714-13714/com.javapapers.android.jsonparsing I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13714 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I don't see any place where the `adapter` from `MainActivity` would be initialized so it's probably because of that as you've noticed by yourself.

Comment: It's this were it gets initialized ? ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, dataList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_IBU, TAG_ABV},
                    new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.ibu, R.id.abv });

Comment: No, it initializes a local variable with the same name and of different type, ie `ListAdapter`, vs `ArrayAdapter<String>` of the field of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You a create local variable named `adapter` as well in `onPostExecute()`, and then in text change listener you call the global one.

Just call:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, dataList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_IBU, TAG_ABV},
            new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.ibu, R.id.abv });
```

Without instantiating a new object.